# Hashing in original mail.log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, logging, devops

```
import hashlib
import re
import shutil
import time

def process_logs(start_line):
    global num_new_logs
    with open('/root/replace2.log', 'r') as file:
        logs = file.readlines()
    with open('/root/replace2.log', 'a' if start_line > 0 else 'w') as file:
        for i in range(start_line, len(logs)):
            line = logs[i]
            matches = re.findall(r'[<\"](\S+@\S+)[>\"]', line)
            for mail_id in matches:
                prefix = mail_id[:2]
                domain = extract_root_domain(mail_id)
                hashed_mail_id = hashlib.sha256(mail_id.encode()).hexdigest()[:5]
                updated_line = line.replace(mail_id, f"{prefix}_{hashed_mail_id}@{domain}")  
                file.write(updated_line)
        num_new_logs = len(logs)



def extract_root_domain(email):
    parts = email.split('@')
    domain_parts = parts[1].split('.')
    if len(domain_parts) > 1:
        return domain_parts[-2] + '.' + domain_parts[-1]
    return parts[1]

def monitor_logs():
    global num_new_logs
    while True:
        process_logs(num_new_logs)
        time.sleep(60)

num_new_logs = 0
monitor_logs()
```

I have created this python script

1. It extracts the root domain (extract_root_domain)
2. Reads the log file processes all the logs line by line and replace the email id with first two characters of the email_id username followed by underscore and hashed value using sha256 then the @domain_name as it is.
3. Monitor function with infinite loop to execute the process_log function after every 60 seconds.

Purpose: i need to replace the all the email_ids in the original mail.log file and replace all as mentioned in second step, it should be continues if new log comes then it's mail id also has to be with the modification mentioned in the 2nd step.

If anyone resolved the same issue please do share

Comment: What issue do you mean?

Comment: i need to replace mail id with hashed value as i mentioned the /var/log/mail.log file, 
1) This script is replacing all the existing logs with hashed values of emails
2) but when the new logs come this script will be executed after the 60 seconds, it's not replacing the log with the hashed mail instead it's adding the hashed email below that log

Comment: It's no wonder that _it's adding the hashed email below that log_ if you open it in mode `'a'`.

Comment: if i will open it as 'w' mode it will override the previously processed logs, what else we can do?

Comment: Probably the replacement ID doesn't have the same length as the original mail ID. This means you have to write the part of the log file beginning with line `start_line` completely new (or you create a new file and finally replace the original file with it). To read and write a file there is file mode `r+`.

Comment: if i use read and write mode `r+` it's appending the new logs without replacing the older logs which has been processed and converted to the hash. if you say make a copy of the mail.log file and after processing the logs replace it with the original file but meanwhile when i'm replacing the log file let's say 10 new logs are posted on the original file they also will get vanished because i'm moving the other file content using `mv`
if it's works for you please make changes on above code and provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import hashlib
import re
import shutil
import time

def process_logs(start_line):
    global num_new_logs
    global updated_line
    global logs
    with open('/root/mail.log', 'r') as file:
        logs = file.readlines()
    with open('/root/mail.log','w') as file:
        for i in range(start_line, len(logs)):
            line = logs[i]  
            matches = re.findall(r'[<\"](\S+@\S+)[>\"]', line)
            for mail_id in matches:
                prefix = mail_id[:2]
                domain = extract_root_domain(mail_id)
                hashed_mail_id = hashlib.sha256(mail_id.encode()).hexdigest()[:5]
                updated_line = line.replace(mail_id, f"{prefix}_{hashed_mail_id}@{domain}")
                logs[i] = updated_line  
        #file.write(updated_line)
        file.writelines(logs)
        num_new_logs = len(logs)
        with open('num_new_logs.txt', 'w') as num_file:  
            num_file.write(str(num_new_logs))

def extract_root_domain(email):
    parts = email.split('@')
    domain_parts = parts[1].split('.')
    if len(domain_parts) > 1:
        return domain_parts[-2] + '.' + domain_parts[-1]
    return parts[1]

def monitor_logs():
    global num_new_logs
    with open('num_new_logs.txt', 'r') as num_file: 
        num_new_logs = int(num_file.read() or 0)

    while True:
        process_logs(num_new_logs)
        with open('num_new_logs.txt', 'w') as num_file: 
            num_file.write(str(num_new_logs))
        time.sleep(60)

num_new_logs = 0
monitor_logs()
```

Solved the issue.

> here in updated script reading whole file mail.log file.
> stored that whole file in the list.
> processed all the logs in the list one by one using forloop and stored the same in the logs list.
> And taken all the logs replaced all the of the log file.